# Difference between Ajax return Response function and only return

Tags: javascript, ajax, return

What is the difference between having the following in an ajax request / call (is it request or call?)

```
return $output;
```

and

```
return Response($output);
```

both work, but Response does not give me information about the returned element while return only does give me information.

Comment: We have no idea what `$output` or `Response` are. While JavaScript *can* use variables starting with a `$`, it isn't common outside of jQuery, so I have my doubts that your code is even JavaScript (despite your tags).

Comment: @Adriani6 — There is, but I've never seen anyone instantiate one manually. It's normally created by the internals of fetch.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, I removed my comment - I realized that. Sorry :-)

Comment: [Just going to leave the link to documentation here...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Comment: This is embarassing, sorry this is an ajax call which sends something to a php file. so this is indeed php.

Comment: @user11186057 — PHP doesn't, AFAIK, have a built-in `Response` function, and you'd normally use `echo` to output data, not return. So this seems to be a question about a specific PHP framework which you haven't named (and the Ajax side of things is entirely irrelevant since you're just dealing with a generic HTTP response).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AJAX is a call actually but as we are requesting to server for send us response against some query that's why we call it AJAX request.

I'm not so sure but **Reponse($output)** in PHP yields you the modified response from server, by modified response I mean the filtered information to your request and **response($output)** gives the whole body of response coming from Back end.